# WiFiAdapter.ConnectAsync returns NetworkNotAvailable but network IS available

Tags: .net, windows, wifi, access-point

I am using WiFiAdapter class on a c# application to connect remote access point.

The PC I am working on has a WiFi interface and a wired LAN interface.

The application scans the available AP to find a specified SSID,

```
public async Task<WiFiAvailableNetwork> Scan(String SSID)
{
        WiFiAvailableNetwork network = null;
        var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();
        var result = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(WiFiAdapter.GetDeviceSelector());
        if (result.Count >= 1)
        {
            wifiAdapter = await WiFiAdapter.FromIdAsync(result[0].Id);
            await wifiAdapter.ScanAsync();

            //sp.Children.Clear();
            foreach (var item in wifiAdapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks)
            {
                if (SSID.Equals(item.Ssid))
                    network = item;
            }
        }
        return network;
}
```

Once it had found the network I connect to this using password credentials:

```
    private async Task<bool> Connect(WiFiAvailableNetwork network, String password)
    {
        WiFiReconnectionKind reconnectionKind = WiFiReconnectionKind.Automatic;
        WiFiConnectionResult result = null;

        if (network.SecuritySettings.NetworkAuthenticationType == NetworkAuthenticationType.Open80211)
        {
            result = await wifiAdapter.ConnectAsync(network, reconnectionKind);
        }
        else
        {
            var credential = new PasswordCredential();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                credential.Password = password;
            }
            
            result = await wifiAdapter.ConnectAsync(network, reconnectionKind, credential).AsTask();
        }

        return (result.ConnectionStatus == WiFiConnectionStatus.Success);
    }
```

This method always works when I am working on the PC which runs the application.

When I am connected via remote Desktop to the PC which runs the application and the remote desktop connection exploits the wired interface, this method sometimes works for a while but at a certain moment I can not connect any access point. The *ConnectAsyn* method returns *ConnectionStatus.NetworkNotAvailable*. However I can connect the same AP using the Windows interface.

In this situation the only solution I found to make ConnectAsyn work again is to logout from my account and login again.

It looks like a bug of this class in this very particular situation which unfortunately is the standard mode in which my application should work.